# Regras Firebase - Apenas meu site Ler e escrever dados

Tags: firebase

Tenho um formulário simples e público que criei para um pessoal cadastrar informações.
Nada de autenticação.

Atualmente meu Realtime database está com as regras em Default:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

Como escrevo uma regra que apenas meu form leia e escreva nesta coleção de dados?
Observando assim, os dados podem ser manipulados publicamente tendo acesso as informações de autenticação.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

se não tiver algum tipo de autenticação não há como assegurar por (via das regras acesso do rtdb) o acesso por qualquer cliente externo.
há algumas maneiras que pode contornar isso que tenho em mente.
você pode criar uma cloud function que duplica o que for escrito para um lugar seguro no rtdb que só você tenha acesso. assim você não precisa se preocupar com manipulação de terceiros.
você pode também tentar fazer é para criar uma camada a mais de proteção é todo acesso ao seu site criar um usuário anônimo automaticamente e proteger com suas regras com .write ou .read": "auth != null. porém ainda sim alguém pode fazer login fora do ambiente do seu site já que é um login anônimo. mas já pode resolver.
por fim para ter 100% de seguranca voce precisa de autenticação